# Where am I best to ground myself when using a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: computer-science, raspberry-pi4

I use a Raspberry Pi 4 with various pieces of equipment such as a Sense Hat and a Pi Camera.

I am aware that a static shock could ruin my equipment and so I bought an ESD wristband with a wire and a crocodile clip on the end.

I am meant to attach the crocodile clip to something that can ground me but I don't know what. The RPi doesn't have a metal case, plug sockets don't have anything to attach it to, etc. The only metal thing I have where I work is a metal table lamp.

Would clipping the wristband to the lamp ground me and if not, what should I ground myself with?

I have not tested using the table lamp as I don't want it to not work and end up ruining equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really not worry about ESD when dealing with a Raspberry Pi. So just forget your ESD wristband and enjoy experimenting and working with your boards and its peripherals.

Comment: Just a quick question, if there is no need to worry about ESD, why do pi peripherals need anti-static bags? Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).